# Does there Exist a Set Such That $\mathcal{P} (A) \subseteq A $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It is an homework question in Introduction to Set Theory class.
I've tried to prove by contradiction that such a set doesn't exist, because if it does, then $A\in A$, but I miss the contradiction.

$A \in A$ is the basis for Russell paradox, but the contradiction, as I understand it, lies in the definition of A.

I am not allowed to use the ZF axioms.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use the ZF axioms." Then what CAN you use? How do you define a set?

Comment: This is not possible as elements of P(A) are subsets containing elements of A

Comment: Do you know "Cantor's theorem", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem. $P(A)\subseteq A$ contradicts Cantor's theorem.

Comment: The instructor suggests that russell paradox may be useful. However, we've defined the restricted comprehension principle.
@sigmabe I know it but we didn't mention it in the class.

Comment: @Lior You mention "the restricted comprehension principle" but you didn't define it - what is it? (I suspect it is "For every set $X$ and every property $P$, the collection of $x\in X$ with property $P$ is a set", in which case the Russell-style argument Mitchell and I outline in our answers works, but I want to make sure.)

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the lines of Russell's paradox, as your instructor suggested.

Assume that $\mathscr{P}(A)\subseteq A.$

Let $W=\{x\in A \mid x\not\in x\}.$  Then $W$ is a subset of $A,$ so, by our assumption, $W$ is a member of $A.$

Now proceed just as in Russell's paradox to get a contradiction:

We know that for all $x\in A,$ $x\in W$ iff $\dots.$

Answer (score 2):

You write that you are not allowed to use the ZF axioms, but you don't clarify what axioms you *are* allowed to use. As it turns out, you need to use *some* assumptions. There are meaningful set theories in which $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq A$ can happen. For example, in [New Foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) the universal set $V$ exists and satisfies $\mathcal{P}(V)\subseteq V$.

We *can* rule out $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq A$ if we have an appropriate **separation** principle. A separation principle is an axiom of the form "for every set $X$, the collection $Y=\{x\in X: \varphi(x)\}$ is a set" for some property $\varphi$. Specifically, suppose $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq A$ and let $$B=\{a\in A: a\not\in a\}.$$ Then:

- $B\subseteq A$, so $B=a$ for some $a\in A$.
- But is $a\in a$? Well, by definition of $B$, $a\in a$ iff $a\not\in B$. But $a=B$, so this is a contradiction.